# Angular 9 - Component Inputs and Outputs Performance tuning

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9 where in my app I have built a table. Each table cell is its own component. There are about 10 cells per row.

The cell component looks similar to this:

```
<cell
      [name]="obj.name"
      [field1]="obj.field1"
      [field2]="obj.field2"
      [field3]="obj.field3"
      [field4]="obj.field4"
      [field5]="obj.field5"
      [field6]="obj.field6"
      [field7]="obj.field7"
      [field8]="obj.field8"
      [field9]="obj.field9"
      [field10]="obj.field10"
      (onEvent1)="someFn1()"
      (onEvent2)="someFn1()"
      (onEvent3)="someFn1()"
      (onEvent4)="someFn1()"
     ></cell>
```

The current issue is if there are many rows in the table ie more than 25 it can be slow to load and sluggish to interact. I've setup ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy which has improved performance. I am trying to find other things that may impact and have the following questions:

1. If there are many inputs for the component with onpush strategy, can this impact the performance? If say in above example I pass the obj instead of each individual field, should I see an improvement?
2. Can having many outputs (onEvent1) impact the performance?
3. If the cell component.ts has alot of typescript codes (ie specific functions), will this cause slow loading time or this only dependant on the html template only? Is better moving this code to a service instead?

I appreciate people's input on this as so far most articles talk about onPush strategy and doesn't discuss the above.

Comment: maybe a poor comment but i think you need to take in account that basically the more you put the more memory and calculation are required. If I was you I'll do short tests and benchmark to get an answer all of your questions. Best.

Comment: Could you try to pass only 2 inputs? The object itself, and then an array of strings containing the fields you want.

Comment: @CaioOliveira yes that was my question i pass the object instead does it make a difference. As to Asaaf answer with the stackblitz I confirm it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created 2 tests for your different scenarios (one fat component vs small one), I've checked the time between the `constructor` that create the content and `AfterViewInit` and the results are:

1. **Average** **120** **milliseconds** for the [large component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-sj51kq) (this is the one with many inputs/outputs)
2. **Average** **70** **milliseconds** for the [small component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-utarsm) (on the small component I've create all the content on `field1` so actually all the same data is transferred in both tests)

In the links above I've created 2 stackblitz so you can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for this it is really helpful. My question 1. was instead of passing all the fields, is there a performance improvement if I pass the whole object instead ie your example the cell object. I just tested then and confirm there is an improvement difference. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-sp15rl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yeah, it seems that if you can reduce your inputs there will be great improvement for your app, cheers!

Comment: Ok 2. reducing outputs on large component makes very small difference, 3. having extra code in component doesn't have much of an impact if at all. Thanks for this stackblitz i will definitely use it for further performance tuning.